# Firebase security rules using get() in a function outside match rule

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have found that using the get() call in a function outside the match rule does not work, whereas putting it in the match rule does work:

```
service cloud.firestore {

  // If I put this here, it does not work.
  function isAdmin() {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.permissions.hasAny(['admin']);
  }

  match /myrecord/{property} {
    // If I put the isAdmin() here it works.
    function isAdmin2() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.permissions.hasAny(['admin']);
    }

    allow write: if isAdmin();
  }
}
```

I'd prefer this function to be at a "global" level where I can access it from all match rules. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that I can put it after the top-level match and it works as expected:

```
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {

  // If I put this here, after the top-level match it works
  function isAdmin() {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.permissions.hasAny(['admin']);
  }

  match /myrecord/{property} {
```